# uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL not giving the download URL of the file in response

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, angular7

I´m working on an angular course at the moment and I´m having an issue with the upload of archives into firebase, I get to upload the files but I don't get the download URL in response:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList,
        AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Archivo } from '../uploads/file.modal';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadfileService {

  private basePath: string = '/uploads';
  uploads: AngularFireList<Archivo[]>;

  constructor( public angularFireDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  pushUpload(upload: Archivo) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${upload.file.name}`).put(upload.file);

    uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      (snapshot) =>{
        upload.progress = (uploadTask.snapshot.bytesTransferred / uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes * 100);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
            upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
            upload.name = upload.file.name;
            this.saveFileData(upload);
          });
      }

      private saveFileData(upload: Archivo) {
        this.angularFireDatabase.list(`${this.basePath}/`).push(upload);
      }
 }
```

This is the code I use in my upload service, it tells me that the donwloadURL is deprecated.

I´m looking for the solution atm but I´m not finding anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after googling for a while:

```
      pushUpload(upload: Archivo) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${upload.file.name}`).put(upload.file);

    storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${upload.file.name}`).getDownloadURL().then(ref => {
      this.urlDownload = ref;
    });

    uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      (snapshot) =>{
        upload.progress = (uploadTask.snapshot.bytesTransferred / uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes * 100);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        upload.url = this.urlDownload;
        upload.name = upload.file.name;
        this.saveFileData(upload);
      });
  }
```